# How to configure apache to disable access to some subfolders in the directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I am a newbie to apache administration. Now I would like to host my software release folders in apache which is a subfolder of my software project folder. The structure is as following:

```
software_root_folder:

--- source_code_folder

--- release_version_folder

--- debug_version_folder
```

I would like my release_version_folder and debug_version_folder accessible by browser. So how to configure apache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache configuration directives at many different levels. 
In particular, you can select specific directories in the config file.

Alternatively, you can use .htaccess files in the individual directories.

I suggest you look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html